# How to find absolute difference between two numbers MYSQL

Tags: mysql

What's the best way to find the absolute difference between two numbers in MYSQL so that I may order results?  The below works, only if numberA is larger than numberB, but as you can see this is not always the case.  Is there a good way to do this with one statement?

```
SELECT (numberA - numberB) AS spread 
FROM table 
ORDER BY spread DESC

|-------------------|
| numberA | numberB |
| 5.4     | 2.2     |
| 7.7     | 4.3     |
| 1       | 6.5     |
| 2.3     | 10.8    |
| 4.5     | 4.5     |
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As simple as [that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs):

```
SELECT ABS(numberA - numberB) AS spread 
FROM table 
ORDER BY spread DESC
```

Or, if you want to [select the pair (numberA, numberB) in descending order of their difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac144/2):

```
SELECT numberA, numberB
FROM table 
ORDER BY ABS(numberA - numberB) DESC
```

Comment: This doesn't work if numberA is an unsigned integer; you get `value is out of range` before the ABS can run.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has an [ABS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function for that:

```
select abs(numberA - numberB) as abs_diff
from your_table
ORDER BY abs_diff DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem where my data type was `BIGINT` So the value went `out of range` when `numberB` was greater than `numberA`

ChatGPT came up with the following solution for me:

```
SELECT
    (CASE
        WHEN numberA >= numberB
        THEN numberA - numberB
        ELSE numberB - numberA
    END) AS diff,
...
```

Worked like a charm for me.